# Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `Home` must be a function (received `undefined`)

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, expo

I want to call the function using the key name from the array on the tab.screen component.
my code is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Modal } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Home from '../mainscreen/GeneralScreen';
import Core from '../mainscreen/CoreScreen';
import Docs from '../mainscreen/GeneralScreen';
import ESS from '../mainscreen/GeneralScreen';
import General from '../mainscreen/GeneralScreen';
import HR from '../mainscreen/GeneralScreen';
import Payroll from '../mainscreen/GeneralScreen';
import Server from '../mainscreen/CoreScreen';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const tabcomponents = {
  "Home" : Home,
  "Core" : Core,
  "Docs" : Docs,
  "ESS" : ESS,
  "General" : General,
  "HR" : HR,
  "Payroll" : Payroll,
  "Server" : Server
};

class TabNavigator extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
      super();    
      this.state = {
         dashboardtab:[],                 
      }
      this.tabnavigatorasync();      
    }

  tabnavigatorasync = async () => {
    try {
      const dashboardtab = await AsyncStorage.getItem('dashboardtab');    
      const dashboardtabParse = JSON.parse(dashboardtab);      
      this.setState({dashboardtab: dashboardtabParse});
      //console.log('isi dari tab navigator: ', this.state.dashboardtab);                              
      //console.log('------------------------------------------------'); 
      //console.log('isi dari tab navigator 2: ', this.state.dashboardtab2[0].label);                             
    } catch (error) {      
    }
  }

  render(){
    //console.log('dashboardtab', this.state.dashboardtab);
    const tabnavigatorRender = this.state.dashboardtab.map((item, index) =>
      const tabcomponentsrender = tabcomponents[item.admintab.label];    
      return <Tab.Screen name={item.admintab.label} component={tabcomponentsrender} key={index}/>                         
    );

    return(
          <Tab.Navigator>
            {tabnavigatorRender}            
          </Tab.Navigator>
        )
  }
}

export default TabNavigator;
```

the result appears an error like this:
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `Home` must be a function (received `undefined`)

This is the contents of the array:

```
[
    {
        "tab_id": "home",
        "order": 10,
        "admintab": {
            "label": "Home",                        
        }
    },
    {
        "tab_id": "core",
        "order": 1,
        "admintab": {
            "label": "Core",                        
        }
    },
    {
        "tab_id": "docs",
        "order": 2,
        "admintab": {
            "label": "Docs",                        
        }
    },
    {
        "tab_id": "ess",
        "order": 50,
        "admintab": {
            "label": "ESS",                        
        }
    },
    {
        "tab_id": "general",
        "order": 45,
        "admintab": {
            "label": "General",                        
        }
    },                
    {
        "tab_id": "hr",
        "order": 40,
        "admintab": {
            "label": "HR",                        
        }
    },
    {
        "tab_id": "payroll",
        "order": 42,
        "admintab": {
            "label": "Payroll",                        
        }
    },
    {
        "tab_id": "server",
        "order": 70,
        "admintab": {
            "label": "Server",                        
        }
    }
]
```

is there something wrong with the code i made?

Comment: You can't pass a string instead of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you want to use `Dynamic Component Names`.

- First of all import your tabs.

```
import Home from 'path_to_your_tab_component/Home';
import Core from 'path_to_your_tab_component/Core'; // and so on
```

- Then pass them in the object and give them a key based on their names.

```
const components = {
    "Home": Home
    "Core": Core // and so on
}
```

- Inside the map, create a component from this object.

```
const tabnavigator = this.state.dashboardtab.map((item, index) => {
    const TabComponent = components[item.admintab.label];   
    return <Tab.Screen name={item.admintab.label} component={TabComponent} key={index}/>                         
});
```

Comment: I've updated my code to be like this, but new errors appear.

Comment: I've updated my code to be like this, but new errors appear. Error Unexpected Token on pointer: const TabComponent = components[item.admintab.label];

Comment: i want to show you all my code, but this box mesage answer is limited character..

Comment: I missed `return` before `Tab.Screen`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The error that appears is still the same. I have updated the code on the question page with the latest one

Comment: @satt You have 2 `tabnavigator` names,

Comment: Change `const tabnavigator = ` to another name.

Comment: Or rename `tabnavigator = async () => {`.

Comment: Also, update the code like so: `.map((item, index) => {`. You forgot curly braces. See my answer.

Comment: Good. Happy day :))